# Python: where clause with two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have a DataFrame as follows:

```
data = [[99330,12,122],
   [1123,1230,1287],
   [123,101,812739],
   [1143,12301230,252]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04'], 
              columns=['col_A', 'col_B', 'col_C'])
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index)
for col in df1.columns:
    df1[col+'_mean'] = df1[col].rolling(1).mean().shift()
    df1[col+'_std'] = df1[col].rolling(1).std().shift()
    df1[col+'_upper'] = df1[col+'_mean'] + df1[col+'_std']
    df1[col+'_lower'] = df1[col+'_mean'] - df1[col+'_std']
    df1[col+'_outlier'] = np.where(df1[col]>df1[col+'_upper'] or df1[col]<df1[col+'_lower'], 1, 0)
```

However, the last line gives an error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I want to get a column `col+'_outlier'` which displays `1` if  `df1[col]>df1[col+'_upper']` or if `df1[col]<df1[col+'_lower']`; and display `0` otherwise.

What's the proper way to write this where clause with two conditions?

Comment: does this help? https://towardsdatascience.com/8-ways-to-filter-pandas-dataframes-d34ba585c1b8

Comment: I tried the `|` operator but it didn't work either. I got the same error. I couldn't find anything else there that could help.

Comment: you need to wrap both conditions in parenthesis and use the pipe, like `(...) | (...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [operater precedence table](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) in the official documentation. Highest precedence from top to bottom.
You need to wrap your condition in parenthesis and use pipe `|` instead of `or`.

```
df1[col+'_outlier'] = np.where( (df1[col]>df1[col+'_upper']) | (df1[col]<df1[col+'_lower']) , 1, 0)
```